# Will Upgrading Azure SQL Managed Instance Storage from 512 GB to 1024 GB Improve Performance Based on Premium SSD Size Chart?

Tags: azure, database-performance, azure-sql-managed-instance

I am currently trying to optimize an Azure SQL Managed Instance under the General Purpose Service Tier, equipped with Premium-series memory-optimized hardware, running on 16 vCores with 512 GB of storage.

My goal is to improve the overall performance in terms of IOPS and throughput. Referring to Microsoft's Premium SSD size chart https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/disks-types#premium-ssd-size, it seems that larger disk sizes correspond to higher performance benchmarks.

My questions are:

1. If I increase the storage allocated to my Azure SQL Managed Instance from 512 GB to 1024 GB, will I automatically get the performance enhancements listed for the next tier (P30) in the Premium SSD sizes chart, which suggests 5,000 base provisioned IOPS and 200 MB/s throughput?
2. Are these performance increments applied automatically with the increase in disk size, or is there additional configuration or provisioning required on my part?
3. Importantly, will these performance benefits apply even if I do not fully utilize the disk space? using about 265 /512 GB currently

My understanding is unclear whether simply opting for a larger storage size guarantees a faster SSD tier's performance benefits...

I've tried to increase the vCores to utilize more processing power as the main issue I run into is when many users are trying to pull down data at once from this database, it seems to timeout for some users, and our CPU utilization reaches 100%, if we increase the throughput of the disk reads, will that lead to faster sync times, potentially offsetting the CPU from maxing out or prevent timeouts on the Managed Instance?

Thank you for your guidance and expertise!

Comment: The chart doesn't say that larger disks have better performance. It shows what disk and throughput you get for different tiers. Higher tiers run on faster machines, faster IO connections *and* have bigger disks.

Answer (score 2):

" main issue I run into is when many users are trying to pull down data at once from this database, it seems to timeout for some users, and our CPU utilization reaches 100%, if we increase the throughput of the disk reads, will that lead to faster sync times, potentially offsetting the CPU from maxing out"

If your bottleneck is CPU, adding IOPS won't help.  Use [Query Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver16) to find which queries are using excessive CPU and work to optimize those.

Answer (score 0):

It always very hard to say to if a increase in compute resources will improve performance, it completely depends where the performance bottleneck is in the workload. The best way is just to scale up and measure the performance. You can always scale down if it doesn't bring the performance improvements you need.

But in general, SQL could benefit from more IOPS, but that goes hand in hand with the memory.

CPU utilization of 100% is not something to worry about with SQL,if the CPU goes down after a period of time, for example five minutes or so, it's totally fine. That's just SQL works it takes all the resources it can get when needed.

---

Side note

Sounds like you guys could also benefit from an API or more API, instead of users directly pulling the database

---

And instead of having one instance you could also consider an azure sql elastic pool. With an elastic pool you can just add the database and minimum and maximum resources for the databases and when a lot of users pulling the database it will automatically scale

Answer (score 0):

@DavidBrowne's answer is correct - refer to that (I've given it a thumbs-up).

However, there are some important points about the question you posed, that if someone else had a similar question, would potentially put them on the wrong path.

In Azure SQL Server Managed Instances, you do not have one disk for all your data. Instead, each database file goes on a disk. Therefore, to get to the next tier, your database files *each* need to be 129GB+.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/resource-limits?view=azuresql#file-io-characteristics-in-general-purpose-tier for info - especially "every database file gets dedicated IOPS and throughput that depend on the file size" and then they recommend increasing the file size if it's slow.

Instead, it can be beneficial to have multiple data files per database - so that even though each one has 500 IOPS, the total can be 2000 IOPS - and you don't need to have the files being unnecessarily massive.

[Erik Darling has a good writeup of this.](https://erikdarling.com/simple-test-results-for-query-i-o-performance-on-azure-sql-managed-instance/)

In terms of fixes - Once you have identified problematic queries, I've found the following helps a lot

- Use tempdb for as much of your processing as possible. tempdb is stored on a local SSD, not on network storage, and is much faster

  - e.g., if you have a stored procedure that updates the data multiple times, it's better to instead keep the data in tempdb then update it once only.
- Improve indexing - this means fewer reads in general, as well as less CPU overhead (as so much of CPU overhead is on sorting)

Comment: That's an important distinction, Thanks for explaining!

_"In Azure SQL Server Managed Instances, you do not have one disk for all your data. Instead, each database file goes on a disk."_

So if my Managed instance has 9 databases, I then have 9 data files (which querying sys.master_files states seems to indicate that's the case, each varying in size)

I would then need to increase the data files size not the Managed Instances total Disk Size to get onto the next tier.

Comment: Well, you could increase _some_ of the databases to get them to the next tier, and leave others at the original size. However, I think you'd want to also do both the data file and the log file for any database, meaning one database on its own would be at least 260GB to get to the next tier. And when I was doing some testing on my own for this prior to shifting from on-prem to the Azure Managed Instances, I realistically found little difference between the base tier and the next one, although your results may differ.